# Count the number of words in WordList that start with a "q"

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

How can I create a subset of WordList[] that contains only the words that start with "g"?

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to give a title to a question that asks for a different thing than the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select` or `Count` or `CountsBy` with [`StringStartsQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringStartsQ.html):

```
Select[StringStartsQ["g"]]@WordList[]
Short @ %
```

> {gab, gabardine, gabble, gabby, << 1213 >>, gyro, gyroscope, gyroscopic}

To get the counts

```
Length @ Select[StringStartsQ["g"]]@WordList[]
```

> 1220

```
Count[WordList[], _?(StringStartsQ["g"])]
```

> 1220

```
CountsBy[StringStartsQ["g"]] @ WordList[]
```

> <|False -> 38907, True -> 1220|>

Comment: The OP is asking for a subset, not how many are there... I thing you should remove `Length` and `Count`

Comment: @J42161217, good point. I went with the title: "Count the ..."